# Comparison of two modelling function's graphs. Intrepetation

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, mathematical-modeling

Here we have a function $g(t)=12.7e^{-0.098\cdot t}$ and another $f(t)=12.7 \cdot (e^{-0.098t}- e^{-3.29t})$.

$f(t)$ can be rewritten as $f(t)=g(t) - 12.7e^{-3.29t}$

Here are the graphs
[image: the blue graph is g(t) and the black one, f(t)]

I am trying to observe the resemblance of these two functions, but I fail to understand the interpretation of $f(t)$ in this case. First I thought that the function $f(t)$ could be shifted in some way by  $12.7e^{-3.29t}$, which is the difference between $g(t)$ and$ f(t)$ but this is not a constant, it is a function itself. What does this difference represent and how to interpret it here?

Edit:

I suppose it is good to clarify the utility of these models. $f(t)$ is supposed to represent the concentration of a digested tabled in a body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $y=12e^{-0.098t}$ describes the asymptotic behavior of the data, the values as $t$ becomes large, which apprear to be when $t>2$ in this model.

However, $g(t)$ does not account for the behavior of the data when $0\le t<2$.

For that data range the model must be adjusted by an amount $-e^{-3.29t}$.

This allows the model to account for the data when $t<2$ while having a negligible effect on the model for data when $t>2$ since $-e^{-3.29t}$ is small when $t>2$.

Comment: Thank you, could it also have to do something with the derivative of $f(t)$ in respect to time? As I still do not see the significance of $g(t)$, you say that it models the asymptotic behavior, while it is still identical to $f(t)$ in when $t>2$

Comment: Actually, I misspoke. I meant to say that $y=12.7e^{-0.098t}$ models the asymptotic behavior of the data. Logically, the model should return a value of $0$ when $t=0$, but $y=12.7e^{-0.098t}$ returns a value of $12.7$ when $t=0$. Subrtacting $12.7e^{-3.29t}$ causes the model to return a value of $0$ when $t=0$ while better fitting the data when $0\le t<2$.

Comment: What is the purpose of modeling the asymptotic behavior to better fit the data for $0\le t<2$?

Comment: Evidently the researcher thought that the data suggested an exponential decay model for the long-term data. But expotential growth and decay models always have an initial non-zero value at $t=0$, so that requires a modification to model the initial behavior of the data since the initial value is zero. So the researcher used an exponential difference decay model $y=P(e^{-at}-e^{-bt})$ with $b>a$.